# I suddenly got windows firewall pop-up to allow oobe.exe through it. What should I do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall

**Initial story:**
I was using laptop(Just mostly general things like Internet browsing using chrome/edge, spotify, steam game in past 2-3 hours), went away for sometime like for 30 mins, and when I came back there was a pop-up from windows firewall *(The normal pop-up which comes after installation of a app to allow it or not through firewall with option such as public and private networks)* for oobe.exe app with owner showing as microsoft, But I did not did any update or any new installations recently.

Popup just like this, don't have actual snap, so adding this as example - [Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHa2n.jpg) - popup just like this suddenly showed up with name as UseroobeBroker.exe, publisher as microsoft and path as C:\Windows\System32\oobe\UserOOBEBroker.exe

**What I did?**
As it seemed wierd to me that why a microsoft app will need permission, it should already have it. I thought it could be a virus in disguise of oobe.exe app. So I did not did anything and just closed that pop-up.

**Then:**
Task manager stopped updating in real time, So I researched and found that its real time update was automatically paused, so I set it to normal speed again.

**My question:**

1. What was this that happened, should I do anything next?
2. Is oobe.exe required for Win10 OS operations and what is its purpose?
3. Should I go to firewall settings and allow this app again if it is really needed?

**More info:**

1. Path for application for which firewall pop-up came -> C:\Windows\System32\oobe\UserOOBEBroker.exe
2. This is my personal laptop not a office one.
3. Recently I installed nothing, Only some automatic updates like windows or software updates were done automatically.
4. I might have went to some unsecure website but I do not think that it can do this much, like installing malicious app on its own and asking firewall permission. But still a chance for virus. I also scanned PC with MS Windows Defender to be careful, it also did not detected anything.

Comment: OOBE, also stands for Out of Box Experience, is a program that lets you answer questions to then make windows ready for the user. It is common that oobe launches after a windows upgrade to a newer windows 10 build and set things up. If your laptop is from work, it is possible they pushed something to initiate the OOBE.

Comment: I can't find any file named `oobe.exe`. The closest I can come is `C:\Windows\System32\oobe\msoobe.exe`. It looks like a rogue program. Are you sure your computer is not infected? I suggest you find this file named `oobe.exe` and check it on [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/).

Comment: @harrymc,  This is the path for the file for which firewall popup came ->  C:\Windows\System32\oobe\UserOOBEBroker.exe
I have also added it in the question now. I am not sure but I think my computer may not be affected because, I did not downloaded or installed anything recently and also to make sure I did Full Scan with windows defender but it did not detected anything. But still there could be shance of that.

Comment: @LPChip, Yeah but this is personal laptop not a work laptop and I did not initiate or update anything on my own, it could be just window or software that might be updated automatically. And also, in the past I have never seen a pop-up come suddenly asking for a firewall permission, As far as I know I have got this popup only after I installed something but this time I didn't anything, popup just came. And if it is windows OS app only UserOOBEBroker.exe then should not it already have permissions.  Never saw any windows OS app in the past asking firewall permissions. Thats why it was wierd

Comment: @LPChip Can you tell me what is this C:\Windows\System32\oobe\UserOOBEBroker.exe and what does it actually do and if it is widows OS services or app then why it was asking firewall permissions (Using windows 10 for many years, but this happened 1st time)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the article [What is UserOOBEBroker.exe or User OOBE Broker in Task Manager?](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-useroobebroker-exe#:%7E:text=the%20useroobebroker.exe%20is%20an%20executable%20file%20developed%20by%20microsoft.%20it%20is%20an%20integral%20part%20of%20windows%2011%2F10%2C%20the%20oobe%20in%20the%20process%E2%80%99%20name%20stands%20for%20out%20of%20box%20experience.),

> the UserOOBEBroker.exe is an executable file developed by Microsoft. It is an integral part of Windows 11/10, the OOBE in the process’ name stands for Out of Box Experience.

It's not a new process and has been part of Windows operating system for a while:

> One may think that what was the need for such a process in Windows 10 when everything is almost similar to previous version’s but we can bet you are wrong here. The process is a part of our lives since the good old days of Windows XP. Yes, it is true, the major work of this process is to guide you throughout the initial installation process when you set up the system.

You can stop it by following the steps below:

> [image]
>
> - Press the Win + I keys, the Settings App will open up.
> - Click on System
> - On the left section click on Notifications and actions.
> - Uncheck the box for Show me the Windows welcome experience after updates and occasionally when I sign in to highlight what’s new and suggested.
>
> Now restart your system and check for the process in Task Manager. This will also stop the UserOOBEBroker.exe process and prevent it from running.

Comment: Yeah, I am using windows from years, I have even used win7 or XP when I was kid. But I want to ask, that if it is internal process or app required or part of OS then why did it ask me for firewall permissions., should not it already have it? . And if it really needed permission then why did not it ask before, I am using this new personal laptop from 2 years with win10 (used windows 10 too from at least 6 years in my old PC). So why did not it asked the permission before. Can it be virus posing as oobe from microsoft. I have editted question and added snapshot.